# Python/Pandas: conditionally collapse rows, keep most common value, and sum counts

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large pandas dataframe with common sentences 'S', which I'd like to learn, and their counts 'C', like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"S": ["Yes.", "Yes!", "Yes?",
                       "No?", "No.", "What?"],
                 "C": [100, 50, 40, 30, 10, 5]})
df
       S    C
0   Yes.  100
1   Yes!   50
2   Yes?   40
3    No?   30
4    No.   10
5  What?    5
```

If sentences are the same up to their last character, I'd like to collapse them into one, represented by the most common sentence, while adding up the counts across the group. The resulting dataframe should look like this:

```py
       S    C
0   Yes.  190
1    No?   40
2  What?    5
```

In the same way, I have list of common words - some lowercase, some uppercase - and I'd like to add the counts across the lower/uppercase group while retaining only the most common case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a column for 'S' until the last character in the string

```
df['s'] = df['S'].str[:-1]
```

Then you can use groupby() to sum up 'C' and get the most common occurrence in 'S'. Example

```
most_common = df[df['C'] == df.groupby('s')['C'].transform('max')][['S', 's']]
total = df.groupby('s')['C'].sum().reset_index()
most_common.merge(total).drop(columns=['s']).sort_values(by='C', ascending=False)
```

Same for uppercase/lowercase using str.lower()

Comment: Thanks. A remaining issue is that max returns multiple entries if several entries have the same highest count. Adding `most_common = most_common.drop_duplicates(subset='s', keep="first")` solves this.

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do it

```
# using replace, remove the punctuation characters with empty string
# then groupby with sum

(df.assign(text=df['S'].str.replace('[\.|!|\?|\s]', '', regex=True))
 .groupby('text', as_index=False)
 .sum()
 .rename(columns={'text':'S'})
)
```

```
    text     C
0   No       40
1   What      5
2   Yes     190
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a slightly different answer than the one [by crx91](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74022041/13466303), making use of `agg` and `first`.

For sentence endings:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"S": ["Yes.", "Yes!", "Yes?",
                         "No?", "No.", "What?"],
                   "C": [100, 100, 40, 30, 10, 5]})

df = (df
      .sort_values(by=['C'], ascending=False)
      .assign(Sm1=df["S"].str[:-1])
      .groupby('Sm1', as_index=False)
      .agg({'S':'first', 'C':'sum'})
      .drop(columns=['Sm1'])
      .sort_values(by=['C'], ascending=False)
      .reset_index(drop=True))

df
       S    C
0   Yes.  240
1    No?   40
2  What?    5
```

For word case:

```py
dt = pd.DataFrame({"S": ["yes", "Yes", "YES",
                         "no", "No", "what"],
                   "C": [100, 50, 40, 30, 10, 5]})

dt = (dt
      .sort_values(by=['C'], ascending=False)
      .assign(Sl=dt["S"].str.lower())
      .groupby('Sl', as_index=False)
      .agg({'S':'first', 'C':'sum'})
      .drop(columns=['Sl'])
      .sort_values(by=['C'], ascending=False)
      .reset_index(drop=True))

dt
      S    C
0   yes  190
1    no   40
2  what    5
```